# Using packages of the project inside a Ray Task

Tags: python, distributed-computing, ray

I've got a project with some package folders each of which contains a class definition for a feature(e.g. DataProcess class). And there is a main script on the root directory of the project which can access all those package folders. main script creates instances of those classes. If I put those instances(e.g. data_processor object) as arguments to Ray Tasks in order to use their functionalities inside the Ray Tasks, will this work on a cluster setup and all of the nodes can see the methods of data_processor object, or do I have to use something like Ray Runtime Environment and add all those package folders to each node?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use the `working_dir` or `py_modules` fields of runtime environments: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/handling-dependencies.html

This will automatically upload the folders to all nodes on the cluster and set the PYTHONPATH appropriately to make the packages importable in the tasks.